# Find the latest payment value in between "valid" period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

It's quite hard for me to write nice title, so I'll try to describe the problem here in detail.

We have table [dbo].[LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG] that stores the historical data with changed datetimes. In case if the status of the data was NOT IN ('E', 'F', 'I', 'O', 'X') then that means that it was approved at that moment and if the status is other than these ones, then it is not approved. It can become approved and not approved in any order and many times. For example:

```
'2010.01.01', 'A'
'2010.02.01', 'B'
'2010.03.01', 'E'
'2010.04.01', 'Z'
```

That means that the record was approved from 2010.01.01 till 2010.03.01 and then was approved again at 2010.04.01.

There is another table [dbo].[LEASE_FINANCING_AUDIT_LOG] that stores the base payment amount that was at that time. For example if for the same record I would have such entries:

```
'2010.01.01', 123
'2010.04.01', 321
```

then that means that from base payment was 123 from 2010.01.01 till 2010.03.01 (became unapproved) and then from 2010.04.01 the value became to be 321.

There could be various combination of status changes and there could be different  base payment values at any period of times.

So, the goal is to find the LATEST base_payment value that was in between APPROVED period.

Here are the scripts we've made so far. There are 2 tables with that data and the function. Other code snippets are taken from unit tests that's why they are like that and they will output 'bad' string if the logic is not as expected one. The function is working, but I do not really like the TOP 1/ORDER BY approach and trying to find if there is better way to achieve that. Any thoughts?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG]
(
    [LEASE_APPLICATION]       CHAR(8)
  , [APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE] CHAR(1)
  , [CHANGED_DATE]            DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LEASE_FINANCING_AUDIT_LOG]
(
    [LEASE_APPLICATION] CHAR(8)
  , [BASE_PAYMENT]      DECIMAL(10, 2) NULL
  , [CHANGED_DATE]      DATETIME2(7)   NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount] (@lease_application CHAR(8))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
           SELECT TOP 1 lfal.BASE_PAYMENT AS post_approval_payment_amount
             FROM LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG laal
            CROSS APPLY
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 lf.BASE_PAYMENT
                      FROM LEASE_FINANCING_AUDIT_LOG lf
                     WHERE lf.LEASE_APPLICATION = laal.LEASE_APPLICATION
                       AND lf.CHANGED_DATE      < COALESCE((
                                                               SELECT TOP 1 la.CHANGED_DATE
                                                                 FROM LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG la
                                                                WHERE la.LEASE_APPLICATION = laal.LEASE_APPLICATION
                                                                  AND la.CHANGED_DATE      > laal.CHANGED_DATE
                                                                ORDER BY la.CHANGED_DATE
                                                           ), CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59' AS DATETIME))
                     ORDER BY lf.CHANGED_DATE DESC
                )                              lfal
            WHERE laal.LEASE_APPLICATION = @lease_application
              AND laal.APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('E', 'F', 'I', 'O', 'X')
            ORDER BY laal.CHANGED_DATE DESC
       );
GO

DECLARE @lease_application CHAR(8) = '35163328'
      , @base_payment      DECIMAL = 209.12
      , @expected          DECIMAL = 209.12
      , @actual            DECIMAL;

DECLARE @la AS TABLE
(
    change_date             DATETIME2(7)
  , application_status_code CHAR(1)     NULL
  , base_amount             DECIMAL     NULL
  , is_laal                 BIT
);

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'K', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-05-11 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0)
     , ('2017-06-21 14:07:51.2200000', 'X', NULL, 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@expected <> @actual) SELECT 'Test 1 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 1 passed';


SELECT @lease_application = '30000152'
     , @base_payment      = 622.15
     , @expected          = 622.15;

DELETE FROM @la;

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'z', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-05-11 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@expected <> @actual) SELECT 'Test 2 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 2 passed';

SELECT @lease_application = '38768578'
     , @base_payment      = 453.70
     , @expected          = NULL
     , @actual            = NULL;

DELETE FROM @la;

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'L', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-06-09 12:00:36.2000000', 'X', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-06-12 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@actual IS NOT NULL) SELECT 'Test 3 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 3 passed';

SELECT @lease_application = '38282661'
     , @base_payment      = 451.25
     , @expected          = 451.25;

DELETE FROM @la;

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'O', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-05-11 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0)
     , ('2017-07-05 10:52:14.6800000', 'O', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-07-05 11:10:24.0400000', 'E', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-07-05 11:10:25.6000000', 'E', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-07-05 11:10:49.1900000', 'L', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-07-06 00:04:30.6400000', 'O', NULL, 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@expected <> @actual) SELECT 'Test 4 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 4 passed';

SELECT @lease_application = '38768578'
     , @base_payment      = 453.70
     , @expected          = 453.70;

DELETE FROM @la;

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'L', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-05-11 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, 200, 0)
     , ('2017-05-12 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0)
     , ('2017-06-09 12:00:36.2000000', 'X', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-09-18 11:57:13.5100000', NULL, 100, 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@expected <> @actual) SELECT 'Test 5 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 5 passed';

SELECT @lease_application = '38768578'
     , @base_payment      = 453.70
     , @expected          = 453.70;

DELETE FROM @la;

INSERT INTO @la (   change_date
                  , application_status_code
                  , base_amount
                  , is_laal
                )
VALUES ('2017-05-11 03:46:26.4800000', 'L', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-05-11 03:48:05.0600000', NULL, @base_payment, 0)
     , ('2017-06-09 12:00:36.2000000', 'X', NULL, 1)
     , ('2017-09-18 11:57:13.5100000', NULL, 100, 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_applications_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                               , CHANGED_DATE
                                               , APPLICATION_STATUS_CODE
                                             )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.application_status_code
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.lease_financing_audit_log (   LEASE_APPLICATION
                                            , CHANGED_DATE
                                            , BASE_PAYMENT
                                          )
SELECT @lease_application
     , l.change_date
     , l.base_amount
  FROM @la AS l
 WHERE l.is_laal = 0;

SELECT @actual = post_approval_payment_amount
  FROM [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount](@lease_application);

IF (@expected <> @actual) SELECT 'Test 6 failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Test 6 passed';

DROP TABLE [dbo].[LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG];
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[LEASE_FINANCING_AUDIT_LOG];
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[post_approval_payment_amount];
GO
```

Comment: [attempt to follow the question at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2e96/1)

Comment: I can't put it to the fiddle as it is more than 8k characters length. When I tried to minimize the code, then it had other complains

Comment: try rextester.com dbfiddle.uk db-fiddle.com and if there are 6 tests nominate what they are. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I couldn't import my queries to any of your provided services. However I modified the query. Copy/paste it to SSMS (on any database) and execute it. You'll see what does the tests mean.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for some thoughts about alternative approaches.  You could use these ideas individually or in combination:

1. Remember that JOINs may be done using an operator *other* than the equal sign, so you could for example join your tables `ON LEASE_APPLICATIONS_AUDIT_LOG.CHANGED_DATE <= LEASE_FINANCING_AUDIT_LOG.CHANGED_DATE`.
2. The LAG and LEAD functions are highly optimal functions for retrieving "nearby" records.  The third parameter even allows you to specify the value that will be returned in the event a record is not found - a convenient place to insert your `CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59' AS DATETIME` default.
3. Never underestimate the clarity and performance that can be achieved by the proper use of Common Table Expressions (using the WITH clause).

Comment: I know all these points. However I couldn't get the same performance with LEAD function. As I said, that these query currently gives the best performance I could find, but I do not really like how is it written.

Comment: What is it that you don't like?  Too many lines?  Nesting?  Certain keywords?  It would be helpful if you explain what you're trying to achieve by modifying the query.